# Is there a way to simplify $(\frac{a-bc}{b+ac})^{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can this be simplified, or is it already in simplest form?

Edit: By simplest form, I mean the form which would require the least computations to calculate.

Comment: Simplest form is a relative term... for me it is the simplest it can be.

Comment: What is special about this expression? Where is it from? Is it from some step of certain calculation?